# Quickly plotting (number of events) vs. (time) for a very large number of events encoded as pairs of real numbers representing start and end times

Tags: list-manipulation, searching

I have an array that looks like the following:

```
exampleArray = {{t1,r1},{t2,r2},{t3,r3},{t4,r4},{t5,r5},...};
```

Where each pair of real numbers $(t_k,r_k)$ represents some "event" (independent of all other events) starting at time $t_k$ and ending at time $r_k$.  Provided some time $t_i$ and `exampleArray`, I'd like to quickly return the number of "events" at this time.  I'd also like to quickly plot the number of events versus time over some interval.  The catch is that `exampleArray` might have a very large number of elements, so we wouldn't want to scan through it multiple times.

Is there an elegant way to do this in Mathematica?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, make up some data in the form of the exampleArray:

```
startTimes = RandomReal[{0, 100}, 50];
endTimes = startTimes + RandomReal[{0, 10}, 50];
ex = Transpose[{startTimes, endTimes}]
```

Here's a function to find how many of the pairs straddle the value `t`:

```
sel[t_] := Length[Select[ex, #[[1]] < t < #[[2]] &]]
```

For example, calling sel[25] counts how many of the pairs contain the point `t=25`. Calling

```
sel[#] & /@ {25, 30, 35}
```

shows how many times 25, 30 and 35 are contained. You can plot straightforwardly:

```
ListPlot[Table[sel[t], {t, 1, 100}]]
```

[image]

Comment: Very cool... can we plot with this function?

Answer (score 3):

It's certainly not as fast as the implementations already provided, but have you considered looking at `EventData` and the related functionality introduced in M9?

Using Kuba's data:

```
startTimes = RandomReal[{0, 100}, 100];
endTimes = startTimes + RandomReal[{0, 10}, 100];
events = EventData[Transpose[{startTimes, endTimes}]];
```

Use `SurvivalModelFit` to build a survival model of the data, this is like `LinearModelFit` in that it creates an object with properties. The useful one here is `"EventMatrixPlot"`

```
AbsoluteTiming[SurvivalModelFit[events]["EventMatrixPlot"]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
data = [Sort /@ RandomReal[100, {100, 2}];
```

Now let's get list of beginings and endings:

```
{start,stop}=Transpose[data]
```

Now both `time-start[[i]]` and `stop-time[[i]]` have to be positive:

```
sel2[t_] := Total[UnitStep[t - start] UnitStep[stop - t]]


Plot[Total[UnitStep[t - start] UnitStep[stop - t]], {t, 0, 100}]
```

[image]

---

**Speed comparison**:

```
startTimes = RandomReal[{0, 100}, 100];
endTimes = startTimes + RandomReal[{0, 10}, 100];

ex = Transpose[{startTimes, endTimes}];

sel[t_] := Length[Select[ex, #[[1]] < t < #[[2]] &]];
sel2[t_] := Total[UnitStep[t - startTimes] UnitStep[endTimes - t]]

n = 1000;
k = RandomReal[100];
sel[k]~Do~{n} // Timing
sel2[k]~Do~{n} // Timing
```

> ```
> {0.312002, Null}
> {0.015600, Null}
> ```

Comment: seems to be ~10x faster.

Comment: I apologize, but could you explain your answer a little bit?  What is causing the speedup in your opinion?  (NOT a criticism, I'm just being slow)

Comment: @user11745 plotting may seem slow because it's "continuous" plot, not `ListPlot` for 100 values. `sel2` is faster because there are no logical tests, only matrices manipulations. I will update it in a minute with speed comparison.

Comment: @user11745 is it clear now? ;)